# Authorize Attribute is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am trying to use authorize attribute in my mvc 4 web api but it is not working. I know I am missing something but I am unable to find.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public JArray getDistance(string origin, string destination)
    {
       some code..
    }
```

my web.config file is-

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" requireSSL="true" cookieless="UseCookies" name="authcookie"  protection="All" slidingExpiration="false">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

my form authentication cookie is-

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket token = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            UserName,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddHours(24),
            false,
            "user Token"

            );
        string EncToken = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(token);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("authcookie", EncToken);
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

Comment: are you using System.Web.Http namespace?

Comment: @ssilas777 YES I am using it.

Answer (score 1):

For Web API make sure you are using

`System.Web.Http` namespace

not

`System.Web.Mvc`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can [Authorize] controller's actions. but i dont know about trying it on any other methods. few things to consider, check if your cookie is properly cleared or stored during login and logout. you can write a custom authorizaiton filter. check [this](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/api-key-authorization-through-query-string-in-asp-net-web-api-authorizationfilterattribute)

Good luck